Is there a better way for me to modularize my object classes for my Unity game?
For my college game project, I have a Unity 3D third person shooter game where I plan to modularize all the attacks of all enemies units (and the player, after I figure it out). I planned on each attack being initialize-able in the prefab for each type of enemy, since each enemy in the game will be "pre-spawned" into the game. Currently, I want to know if I approached this the right way, or if there are better, more efficient ways to do this, before I finish the logic and debug it.
I created a serializable parent Attack() class with a virtual DoAttack() method, so I can create children classes that can inherit it and implement different behaviors inside the DoAttack() method depending on the type of attack. I currently have three children classes that override the DoAttack() method.
[System.Serializable]
public class Attack
{
    public string Name;
    public float AttackScaling;
    public int StartupTime;
    public int ActiveTime;
    public int RecoveryTime;
    public float MovementForce;
    public float InterruptValue;

    public virtual void DoAttack()
    {

    }
}

public class HitboxAttack : Attack
{
    public Collider attackCollider;

    public override void DoAttack()
    {
        //wait in StartupTime seconds
        //activate attackCollider for ActiveTime seconds
        //wait in RecoveryTime seconds
    }
}

public class ProjectileAttack : Attack
{
    public GameObject projectile;
    public float verticalForce;
    public float horizontalForce;

    public override void DoAttack()
    {
        //wait in StartupTime seconds
        //instantiate projectile using verticalForce and horizontalForce
        //destroy projectile after hit or after ActiveTime seconds
        //wait in RecoveryTime seconds
    }
}

public class CollisionAttack : Attack
{
    public Collider unitCollider;
    public float CollisionSpeed;

    public override void DoAttack()
    {
        //wait in StartupTime seconds
        //charge at player at CollisionSpeed speed using collider for ActiveTime seconds
        //wait in RecoverTime seconds
    }
}

I also created an AttackSequence() class that serves as a container for each attack, mainly to accommodate attacks that are composed of multiple hits. It has a List of Attack() objects and a method that just iterates through the list and executes each DoAttack() in Attack().
[System.Serializable]
public class AttackSequence
{
    public float ActivationRange;
    public List<Attack> Sequence = new();

    public void DoSequence()
    {
        //iterate through each attack in Sequence and call DoAttack()
    }
}

Finally, each enemy unit has an EnemyUnit script that contains a List of AttackSequence() objects, with some logic about how each AttackSequence() object is chosen. (I only included the relevant code)
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyUnit : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform Player;
    public NavMeshAgent Agent;
    public List<AttackSequence> Attacks;

    [Header("Settings")]
    public LayerMask PlayerLayer;
    public float SightRange;
    private float AttackRange;
    public float SafeRange;

    private AttackSequence ActiveAttackSequence;
    private AttackSequence QueuedAttack;

    [SerializeField] private bool IsPlayerInSight;
    [SerializeField] private bool IsPlayerInAttackRange;
    [SerializeField] private bool IsSafeToAttack;
    [SerializeField] private bool IsAttacking;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (IsAttacking) return;

        IsPlayerInSight = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, SightRange, PlayerLayer);
        IsSafeToAttack = !Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, SafeRange, PlayerLayer);

        if (IsPlayerInSight)
        {
            transform.LookAt(Player);
            if (IsSafeToAttack)
            {
                QueuedAttack = ChooseAttack();
                Debug.Log(QueuedAttack);
                if (QueuedAttack != null)
                {
                    AttackRange = QueuedAttack.ActivationRange; //this is for gizmo debugging
                    DoAttackSequence(QueuedAttack);
                }
                else Agent.SetDestination(Player.position);
            }
            else
            {
                Agent.SetDestination(Player.position);
                Agent.speed = -Agent.speed;
            }
        }
        else Agent.SetDestination(transform.position);
    }

    private AttackSequence ChooseAttack()
    {
        List<AttackSequence> DoableAttacks = Attacks.FindAll(attack => Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, attack.ActivationRange, PlayerLayer));
        DoableAttacks.Sort((a,b) => a.ActivationRange.CompareTo(b.ActivationRange));
        return DoableAttacks.Count > 0 ? DoableAttacks[0] : null;
    }

    private void DoAttackSequence(AttackSequence attack)
    {
        IsAttacking = true;
        ActiveAttackSequence = attack;

        //call DoSequence() in attack

        IsAttacking = false;
    }
}


You can't do this .. your list List<Attack> will have all items be serialized just as Attack without knowing which exact implementation they actually are ... you could however rather use a ScriptableObject derived Attack so you can create actual instance assets of them and modify their values
